# enabling ASP.NET hyperlink using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I've created an asp.net hyperlink like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hpAccept" runat="server" Enabled="false" Target="_parent">Hyperlink</asp:HyperLink>
```

as you can see I've defined it as enabled=false, so it is disabled at startup, I've defined a JavaScript function that should enable this hyperlink after a variable is set to true, but it doesn't work! what is my problem, it is my JS function:

```
           function onRadioChange(rowIndex, value) {

.....
....
           if (all_ok) {
               document.getElementById('hpAccept').disabled = false;
           }
       }
```

my variable (all_ok) is set to true but the hyperlink is not enabled!

thanks

Comment: Is this javascript code is inside the page itself?

Comment: yes this function is inside the page, this function performs something more also, and they all do correctly but this line doesn't do anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element's id will not be 'hpAccept'

instead use:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hpAccept.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
```

Comment: have you made sure to return false from any click function to prevent the default postback?

Comment: as I told this function is working fine, but this line doesn't answer as expected, what you mean exactly by click function? of course no postback occurs, but I think that might be a problem, how should I prevent postback?

Comment: for example, if you hook a onclick function then you should do the following: `OnClickFunction() { ...; return false; }`

Answer (score 1):

`<%= hpAccept.ClientID %>` should work but not in a separate javascript file where server side scripts do not execute.

Another possibility is to use a class selector: [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
<input runat="server" id="hpAccept" value="test" class="txtTest" />
```

and then:

```
var value = $('.txtTest').removeAttr('disabled'); //Updated
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm jQuery is a java script library. Anyhow in page source on client machine search `hpAccept`, you should able to find it at two places, the actual control and your javascript.

Comment: this is not XHTML-conform ... either use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` (to disable it) or `.removeAttr('disabled')` (to enable it)

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your HyperLink markup attribute ClientIDMode with value static, it must be looks like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hpAccept" runat="server" Enabled="false" ClientIDMode="Static" Target="_parent">Hyperlink</asp:HyperLink
```

After that, you can use jquery

```
$("#hpAccept").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: -, `hpAccept` is not the rendered id (aka clientID) ... it will get "parented" by the parent-control-ids ... you will get the correct it, by using `<%= this.hpAccept.ClientID %>`

Comment: thanks friend, I could solve my problem, I just added HREF to my hyperlink:document.getElementById('hpAccept').disabled = false;
                   document.getElementById('hpAccept').href = "google.com";